# Display a field from a 3rd table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to display a field from a 3rd table in a relationship, and after checking posts here and the docs, I am still stuck.I have 3 models all related in some way. I have found similar posts here but I am still not getting it to work. I am learning so sorry if I have missed this somewhere in the docs but I have read a fair bit and have tried a lot. I am guessing too much now on this so I need help.

```
 1)Tutorsession - belongsto teachers,
 2)  Teacher -has 1 user,hasmany tutorsessions
 3)    User- has 1 teacher, //////I want to display a field from this table given I display tutorsessions

In controller    
$this->set('tutor',
    $this->Tutorsession->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id),
            'contain' => 'User.username'
        )
    )
); //////////no error but no results

from view  echo '<td>'. $item['User']['username'].'</td>'; ///////error user undefined
```

The tutorsession automatically gets rows from teacher table but not user table witht he model setup on a findall.

I want to display a username from the user table. I display the tutorsession table , I then can display the teacher table with the model association but I cant go from the teacher table to the user table to get a user name from the user id as the common field.  I have checked the docs below and I am not sure why my code isnt ble to display a username from users table.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

```
update: here are the models

class User extends AppModel {

     public $hasOne = array(
        'Teacher' => array(
            'className' => 'Teacher',
            'dependent' => true
        )

class Tutorsession extends AppModel
{
 public $name='Tutorsession';

     public $belongsTo = array(
        'Teacher' => array(
            'className' => 'Teacher',
            'foreignKey' => 'teacher_id'
        )

class Teacher extends AppModel
{

    public $name='Teacher';
    public $hasMany = array('Tutorsession');
     public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
```

Comment: try to debug $item first. debug($item); then paste to your question the result so we can help you. You can add in your controller beofre the quesry , $this->Tutorsession->recursive = 2;
With the result you can see how to access it.

Comment: The array is quite large so I dont know how to fit it in here however it doesnt show anything from the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add containable behavior in your Model

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Execute following query In controller

```
$contain = array('Teacher' => array('User'));
$this->set('tutor', $this->Tutorsession->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id),
        'contain' => $contain
    )));
```

Comment: debug($tutor);  doesnt show any user table still?  I like the code but I cant display the user name still, Undefined index: User     echo '<td>'. $tutor['User']['username'].'</td>';

Comment: I added the line to each model but nothing! same error. It just hates to display this field from a 3rd table. $tutor['User']['username']  //udefined index user

Comment: @ajt: for debuging , Please try after commented conditions in the find.Let me know wt happen.Want to see, have u Teacher data with user_id.

Comment: This is a better solution as you dont use recursive  $contain = array('Teacher' => array('User'));
$this->set('tutor', $this->Tutorsession->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id),
        'contain' => $contain
    )));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->Tutorsession->recursive = 2;
$this->Tutorsession->Teacher->contain('User');
$this->set('tutor',
    $this->Tutorsession->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried using debug and cant see any user table and I tried the abobe but Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'contain' at line 1

Comment: Also tried this with error on where clause 'contain' $this->set(
'tutor',
$this->Tutorsession->find(
'first',
array(
'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id),
'contain' => 'User.username'
)
)
);

Comment: public $actsAs = array('Containable'); I added this in the User model without any change to the error with contain. I am really struggling here to get a simple field from a 3rd table

Comment: solved, I needed to reference the field echo '<td>'. $tutor['Teacher']['User']['username'].'</td>'; and add the containable to models

Comment: setting recursive to -1 makes the things fail again so I dont know how to avoid recursive and contain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tutor=$this->Teacher->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('Teacher.user_id' => $id)
        )
    );

debug($tutor); exit();
```

Your result similar:

```
'Teacher' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'abc',
        'created' => '1397040385',
        'updated' => '1397725860'
    ),


'User' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'administrators',
        'created' => '1397032953',
        'modified' => '1397032953'
    ),


'Tutorsession' => array(
                 0=>array(
                'id' => '3',
                'name'=>'abc',
                'created' => '1400729137'
                   ),
                 1=>array(
                'id' => '4',
               'name'=>'abc',
               'created' => '1400729137'
                  )
              )
```

Ensure your models are correct

Comment: I dont get the user like you do in your debug and how do i add my debug in this small area? My models work fine apart from getting data across 3 tables. The users table has no direct relation to tutorsesion table. The contain users gets an error i cant fix